# getting permission denied while accessing ../build/intermediates/classes/debug/com/test/jni/MainActivity.class

Tags: android, android-ndk

was trying to incorporate android ndk with android studio when i go with the following command getting error permission denied 
where android-19 minimum sdks

$ sudo javah -d jni -classpath /Users/me/home/sdk/platforms/android-19/android.jar;/Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/Jni/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/com/test/jni/MainActivity.class

Comment: First of all sudo is not required to generate header file. May I know where you are running this command? You should simply run javah packagename.youclassname in bin directory

Comment: Thankyou, i am using mac

Comment: I am using this command on ubuntu and as far as I know both are almost same. I faced the same issue that is why I told you